# How to take images for stereo calibration?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

How to take images for stereo calibration : does right/left cameras can take different pictures (point of view, orientation, time, ...) independently or must they take the (as much as possible) "same" pictures at the "same" time ?

I try to use OpenCV to calibrate and rectify/undistort 2 cameras (right/left) of a stereo pair.

At first, I was using standard (non fisheye) cameras, I called `cv2.calibrate` and `cv2.stereoCalibrate` using independent chessboard pictures taken for right/left cameras at different moments : I struggled with `cv2.remap` but the calibration and stereo-calibration steps seemed to be passed (in the sense "it didn't crash!") and I was like "OK, the logic looks like one need to calibrate each camera independently, and then, one need to stereo calibrate both of them based on individual left/right calibrations (I am new to the field)".

Then, I got 2 fisheye cameras : I tried to go the same way using `cv2.fisheye.calibrate` and `cv2.fisheye.stereoCalibrate` but ended up into this kind of crash `fisheye.cpp:1051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) abs_max < threshold in function 'stereoCalibrate'`.... Which seems to be possibly related to the way pictures may be taken and the fact that left/right pictures (obj/img points found on pictures) are "too much" different (https://answers.opencv.org/question/67855/opencv-error-assertion-failed-abs_max-threshold-in-stereocalibrate/)

At last, I realized some examples I found on the web are indeed taking pictures from left/right at the same time (2 successives lines of code in a script which is ran once - this is not what I do, I just have 1 line of code for 1 camera and I must run the script twice!) : is this intentional (or necessary ?) to take correlated pictures for the stereo calibration to pass ?

Comment: all cameras need to take a picture of the same scene. if the scene changes, that means they need to take a picture at the same time. this is necessary. what would be the point of taking **unrelated** pictures? that's not gonna establish any relationship between the cameras, right? right.

Comment: Totally new to the field. Mislead by the idea of calibrating first camera alone, then together. Make sense afterwards.

Comment: With my CSI cameras (need OpenCV + gstreamer) seems I can not open 2 streams at the same time...

Comment: Like two eyes: https://www.theimagingsource.com/newsletter-2.0/20171004/body.en_US.phtml